# Unable to add existing css and assets folder to wwwroot folder in ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-webpages

I created new ASP.NET Core 3.1 web project.

What I am trying to do is to style my application based on some paid theme so I copied all CSS and assets folder to the `wwwroot` folder and then when I tried to reference those to html in Layout html or anywhere else my css and js is not getting applied to my html.

Can anyone explain why?
Below is the directory structure I have added inside lib folder _scss folder and assets folder

[image]

[image]

Comment: try hitting hard refresh (ctrl + F5).  are you able to access http://localhost:<port>/css/app.css from your browser?

Comment: Put your html code and your directory structure here to help you

Comment: Please provide how you reference the css and js files, and your directory structure.

Comment: @Chen I have updated the images for folder structure and the html layout page

Comment: What errors are displayed in the DevTools? Not Found or others? Is there this line of code in the Startup file: `app.UseStaticFiles();`？

Comment: Try to use `~/`, not `./`.

Comment: I figured that I am using scss and in html file I am using .css so I have to compile it using web compiler